# Integración a través de dos funciones en python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Hola estoy haciendo un programa que mediante el método de Ritz nos de las frecuencias principales de una placa. Para ello uno de los pasos es la multiplicación de dos funciones de x, y su posterior integración el problema viene en que la integracion no se realiza de forma correcta y no se por qué.

Aqui dejo parte del codigo.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot  as plt

def X(x,i):
    X= np.sqrt(2)*np.sin(i*np.pi*x/a)
    return X

def I00(x,i,m):
    I00=X(x,i)*X(x,m)
    return I00

integrate.quad(I00,0,a,args=((mm+1),(i+1)))[0]
```

Tanto i como m son variables que se van variando dentro de un bucle.

Comment: ¿qué significa no se realiza en forma correcta? ¿qué tiene que dar? ¿qué valores tiene mm, i y a? Imagino que usas numpy y scipy, si es así agrega esas etiquetas a tu pregunta, al menos la etiqueta de scipy. Y de paso agrega también los import.

Comment: Que al evaluar las integrales para un determinado m,n y a los resultados no concuerdan con los ofrecidos por ejemplo con la misma integral hecha en wolfram, muchas gracias por lo de las etiquetas lo tendre en cuenta.

Comment: Gracias por la edición. Pero sin dar ejemplos de los valores que pasas (5? 0? 10^-10? 10^10?) lo único que se me ocurre es que estás pasando mm e i al revés.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, tienes razon, por ejemplo para los valores de: a=0.85 i=mm=0, la integral debería de dar 4.8.. y sin embargo obtengo 0.85

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con esos parámetros a=.85, i=m=0, la función que has programado nunca va a integrar en 4.8 para el intervalo [0,1].

El máximo es 2 y esa sería su integral si la función fuera constante y=2.

Te recomiendo graficarla (usa una Jupyter notebook) o como mínimo imprimir una tabla con valores entre 0 y 1 (cada 0.1 o 0.05) para ver la salida de tu función.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate

mm=0
i=0
a=.85

def X(x,i):
    X= np.sqrt(2)*np.sin(i*np.pi*x/a)
    return X

def I00(x,i,m):
    I00=X(i,x)*X(m,x)
    return I00

integrate.quad(I00,0,1, args=(mm+1,i+1) )[0]

[Out] 0.8789007867104668

xs = np.arange(0,1.05,0.05)
ys = I00(xs, 1, 1)
plt.plot(xs, ys)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, duda resuelta.

Comment: @user21428 ¿podrías marcarla como buena usando la marca verde que aparece junto a la respuesta? :)